# Dynamics Connect custom fields sync - "This object is already associated with another model"

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

I am trying to sync custom fields from Dynamics Connector 3.0.0 to xConnect (Sitecore 9.2)
I have extended xConnect model with my custom facet, mapped fecet definitions,  value accessor sets etc, deployed xconnect models as described in the [walkthrough](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/dynamics-crm-connect/30/sitecore-connect-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-for-sales/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-contact-facet.html)

I am getting an exception while trying to execute "Dynamics Contact to xConnect Contact" pipeline batches:

```
START AGGREGATE EXCEPTION (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync, ID: 5, HResult: -2146233088)
  Exception thrown when processing a pipeline batch. (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync)
This object is already associated with another model (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbExtensible.Attach(XdbModel model)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperation.Validate()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1.Validate()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.ValidateOperation(IXdbOperation operation)
  Exception thrown when processing a pipeline batch. (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync)
This object is already associated with another model (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbExtensible.Attach(XdbModel model)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperation.Validate()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1.Validate()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.ValidateOperation(IXdbOperation operation)
END AGGREGATE EXCEPTION (pipeline batch: Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync, ID: 5, HResult: -2146233088)
```

I am not too sure what is wrong. Is that something with the mapping, with the model itself or with value conversion?

I have noticed another thing as well:
If I try to navigate to my xConnect Client Endpoint and press "Show Deployed Models" - Default Dynamics model shows me a warning:
[image]

However I don't know how to see any details about it.
If I decompile the source, it fails on method Sitecore.XConnect.Schema.XdbExtensible.Attach()

specifically at !model.DefinesType(this.XObject.XdbType)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was stupid me who forgot to update the xConnect endpoint configuration and change the target collection model to my custom one. That resulted into data exchange not being able to see the custom model at all.

[image]